# No refresh pages

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Hello I wanna make my website subpages with no refresh but I encountered problem.

thats is my structure of php files

```
index.php
 /pages folder
   add.php
   search.php
   login.php
```

and if i wanna go to add.php i have link ?page=add and the same for rest.
Header and footer, styles, includes are in index.php
I made container #content there should be loaded content from pages folder files.

And what is the problem - when i use this script there is no sending variables from index.php

like `Notice: Undefined variable: _LANG in C:\xampp\htdocs\webpage\search.php on line 34`

but when I dont use this jquery script, all variables are sending and everything is ok. Why is this happening and how to fix that

I made like this

[YT VIDEO](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ytKc0QsVRY4)
so that is my jquery for that script i using modr rewrite so from address, for instance
`/?page=search` = `/search` and then this is exact path `pages/' + page + 'php`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('header ul.header_actions > li > a').click(function(){
         var page = $(this).attr('href');
         $('#content').load('pages/' + page + 'php');
         return false;
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

are you missing a `.`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('header ul.header_actions > li > a').click(function(){
     var page = $(this).attr('href');
     $('#content').load('pages/' + page + '.php');
     return false;
  });
});
```

Comment: right :/ but unfortunately only there when i putted script. on my website still not working. :/

Comment: After reading on this issue some scenarios are sorted by using full urls

Comment: what does it mean . oooll when i putting on browser by hand http://localhost/webpage/pages/add.php that give me same result Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_logged() in C:\xampp\htdocs\webpage\pages\add.php on line 3